# how to delete a table cell in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, each, removechild

How to remove a cell when clicked on `display_removebutton` and rearrange the entire structure
Here is the code which im trying to implement. I have tried with `$("td:empty").remove();` but no use, it is not working
Can any one suggest any modification

```
 var int_loop =  1;
    var flag_tr = 1;
    $('#total').append("<table width=100%>"); 
    
    $(upfiles).each(function(index, file) 
    {
        display_removebutton = "<img width='20px' style='cursor:pointer;' height='20px' class='class_remove' data-id='"+int_loop+"' id='remove_"+int_loop+"' src='images/DeleteRed.png' />";
        if(flag_tr === 1 && int_loop ===1)
            $('#total').append("<tr>"); 
       else if(flag_tr === 6)
             $('#total').append("<tr>");
        $('#total').append("<td class='div_files' id='div_selec"+int_loop+"'><b>File Name :</b>"+file.name + display_removebutton+"</td>" ); 
        if(flag_tr === 6)
        {
              $('#total').append("</tr>");
              flag_tr = 1;
        } 
        $("#remove_"+int_loop).click(function() {
            //REMOVED FILES USING SPLICE SUCCESSFULLY
            
            //How do i remove cell here and rearrange the entire structure
            
            $("td:empty").remove(); //tried with this but no use, it is deleting the entire data in a div
        });
        int_loop++;
        flag_tr++;
    }
```

**Edited 1 :**

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dXwR8/1/)

**Edited 2 :**  Also im doing append correctly for table tags open and close. because tr an tds are not displaying in table tag

Comment: This type of question really needs an example with HTML, preferably in a JSFiddle :)

Comment: why -1 can you explain

Comment: what information still need..  i will provide... i cant post the entire code here and it is not good thing... and also i have stated my problem clearly... still need any info. i will provide

Comment: ok as it is drag and drop input file upload.. i have not provided the entire thing can i provide?

Comment: Please note your HTML is invalid... The TDs are outside the TRs!!!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie im i appending correctly?? what is wrong in the above code abt TD and TR

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie You have not closed table tag in jsfiddle.. how do i close table tag

Comment: See my comment below my answer... You are **not** appending HTML as text. You are creating HTML elements using jQuery. There is no need for a closing HTML tag for elements created that way. Inspect the DOM and you will see they exist already! :)

Comment: can u please tell me how to inspect DOM

Comment: Run it in Google Chrome. Right click on any element and select "Inspect Element". That will open the DOM explorer at the right point. Enjoy :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55805/discussion-between-prassu-and-trueblueaussie).

Comment: @TrueBlieAussie can you help me on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258151/how-to-add-a-file-in-filelist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working version of your jsFiddle with sample data and all fixes:

- You need to remove the `closest` `TD` to the button click.
- You needed to append the `TD`s to the `TR`s and
- You needed to append the `TR`s to the `TABLE`:
- You also wanted a nice transition (fade added)
- You do not want to append closing `</TR>` elements (not needed)
- You should use delegated events for dynamically added elements

### http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/dXwR8/9/

```
// Some sample data
var upfiles = [{
    name: "name1"
}, {
    name: "name2"
}, {
    name: "name3"
}, {
    name: "name4"
}, {
    name: "name5"
}, {
    name: "name6"
}, {
    name: "name7"
}

];

var int_loop = 1;
var flag_tr = 1;
$('#total').append("<table width=100%>");

$(upfiles).each(function (index, file) {
    display_removebutton = "<img width='20px' style='cursor:pointer;' height='20px' class='class_remove' data-id='" + int_loop + "' id='remove_" + int_loop + "' src='images/DeleteRed.png' />";
    if (flag_tr === 1 && int_loop === 1) {
        $('#total table').append("<tr>");
    } else if (flag_tr === 6) {
        $('#total table').append("<tr>");
    }
    $('#total tr:last').append("<td class='div_files' id='div_selec" + int_loop + "'><b>File Name :</b>" + file.name + display_removebutton + "</td>");
    if (flag_tr === 6) {
        $('#total').append("</tr>");
        flag_tr = 1;
    }
    int_loop++;
    flag_tr++;
});
$('#total').on('click', '[id^=remove_]', function () {
    var $td = $(this).closest('td');
    $td.fadeOut(function () {
        $td.remove();
    });
});
```

---

**Old versions below**

---

### Update:

The DOM structure was invalid. You can't add TDs directly to a table. That had to be in a TR. I changed the code to always add to the last TR in the table.

### Another update - transitions:

### JSFiddle: Of course: jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/dXwR8/7

If you want a fade before the remove, remember the element in a local variable, and use the callback of `fadeOut()` to remove the item.

```
    var $td = $(this).closest('td');
    $td.fadeOut(function(){ $td.remove(); });
```

### Yet another update: Delegated events

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/dXwR8/8/

`balachandran` was quite right in suggesting you use a delegated event handler for dynamic items. It simplifies the code.

```
$('#total').on('click', '[id^=remove_]', function () {
    var $td = $(this).closest('td');
    $td.fadeOut(function () {
        $td.remove();
    });
});
```

**Delegate event handlers** work by listening at an *ancestor* of the desired elements, *then* when the chosen event bubbles up to that element, *then* it applies the jQuery selector to find desired elements, *then* it applies the function to any matching elements *that caused the event*.

If you do not have a convenient, non-changing ancestor, use `$(document).on`, but never `$('body').on` as body has some weird side-effects.

Delegated events have several benefits:

1. Simplifies and separates the event code.
2. You do not have the overhead of adding individual handlers to items.

### Final update: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/dXwR8/9/

The `TR`s were not being appended to the added `TABLE` (they were appending to a DIV instead)

I changed the selectors to:

```
$('#total table').append("<tr>");
```

Comment: Okay, sorted the other problems with the TRs and TDs. It should now wrap to a new row correctly after each 5 files.

Comment: Didn't know about 'closest', ty

Comment: It also had an `$('#total').append("</tr>");` that does absolutely nothing. You can only append opening elements or matches open/close sets, not an element close `</whatever>` by itself.

Comment: is it possible to put effects for removing td.. like we fadeOut ... is it possible here

Comment: did i specified correctly about table tag open and close.. as they are not working in the above question.. when i see in firebug tr and tds are not with in table tag

Comment: @prassu: Yes, you were appending TRs to the div and not the table... Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/dXwR8/9/ Will update answer

Comment: you have not closed table tag.. where we need close and how?

Comment: If you create elements with jQuery `$('<element etc>')` then it automatically creates the element node (which has an implicit open and close). **You are not just appending HTML text**. Check the DOM in the F12 Chrome debug tools! PS. You do not need to keep removing the accept to get my attention (that is just annoying). *Just ask!* :)

Comment: @TrueBlieAussie can you help me on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258151/how-to-add-a-file-in-filelist

Comment: Don't forget time zones :) will have a look this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove that event binding inside the each function and make use of `event-delegation` in this context,

```
$('#total').on('click','[id^="remove_"]',function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td:empty').remove();
});
```

Comment: Cleaner, but they *are* adding the event handler, per item, after appending.

Comment: #total is div not a cell

Comment: @prassu It is the static parent, and we can use it for delegating the event...!

Comment: tried as u suggested not working.. i have replaced  **$("td:empty").remove();** with yours

Comment: As I said, this is cleaner (and preferred), but it is not the question/problem they are posing. You also need to explain it better as `prassu` obviously did not understand it (based on their `it's a div` comment). They may have miss-used your code :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie i suggested him to remove the event bindings inside the each function.. :) But he/she not getting the point that i am trying to say..!